# Differential Equation $y'+y\cdot\frac{1}{1+t^2}=1-y\cdot\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have no idea how to do this. I think we let $a(t)=\dfrac{t}{1+t^2}$ so then $\mu(t)=(1+t^2)^{1/2}$, but I can't seem to get the correct answer, which is $$y(t)=\frac{C+\displaystyle\int(1+t^2)^{1/2}(1+t^4)^{1/4}\,dt}{(1+t^2)^{1/2}(1+t^4)^{1/4}}$$  Any help is really appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The given ODE is linear in $y$.
$$\begin{align*}
y'+\frac{t}{1+t^2}y&=1-\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}y\\\\
y'+\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}\right)y&=1
\end{align*}$$
Integrating factor:
$$\begin{align*}\log\mu(t)&=\int\left(\frac{t}{1+t^2}+\frac{t^3}{1+t^4}\right)\,dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\log(1+t^2)+\frac{1}{4}\log(1+t^4)\\
\mu(t)&=(1+t^2)^{1/2}(1+t^4)^{1/4}
\end{align*}$$